# Recommendation: Advanced topics in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations

I have read Srednicki's Quantum Field Theory book. I want to learn more about advanced topics in field theory, such as geometry and topology in field theory, topology defect, anomaly, soliton, instanton, renormalization，advanced application in condensed matter physics and so on. Does anyone have anything recommended? Thanks

Comment: What you're asking is quite broad, but a great book which covers a significant portion is Weinberg's "Classical Solutions to Quantum Field Theory." It includes solitons, instantons, the Coleman-de Luccia bubble, topology, etc. I'm sure you can find a free PDF online.

Comment: @JamalS: While I cannot find anything on [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?page=3&tab=relevance&q=copyright%20books) suggesting that telling someone to steal copyrighted material is not allowed, I honestly think it's bad form. You should suggest using libraries or Amazon instead.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27700/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8441/2451 and links therein.