# Notation on four-vectors using imaginary spacelike components

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors, complex-numbers, wick-rotation

Can one just change the notation of four vectors so as instead of having $$ X^{\mu} =(X^0, \vec{X})$$we define $$ X^{\mu}=(X^0,i\vec{X})?$$ This way we could use the Euclidean metric instead of $$g^{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1).$$

Comment: Older books tend to do this I think (they put the $i$ in the time component though). As for why people swapped - another user might have opinions on this.

Comment: Why do you want to pretend that the metric is Euclidean, and spacetime is complex, when neither is true? (Yes, I know there are some reasons in QFT for doing this.)

Comment: @G.Smith why do you say that neither are true? If they are mathematically equivalent, they should both be ""true"", whatever true means

Comment: I suppose that is one way to think about it. It isn’t my way of thinking about it. I see no reason to think that meter sticks or clocks are measuring imaginary distances and times rather than real ones.

Comment: I consider all measurable quantities to be real. In any case, this was a former way of doing relativity that has fallen out of fashion, so if you do it you will look 50 years out of date.

Comment: So you allow measures to be negative? Because, couldnt you say with that reasoning, that measures are always positive, and depending on the direction of the measure you put a negative sign in front or not, therefore negative numbers dont exist neither?

Comment: Pretty much everyone today allows spacetime intervals to be either positive or negative. That is the whole point of time-like vs. space-like intervals, and light-cones.

Comment: @G.Smith yeah, I understand it is pretty old-fashioned. Now this raises to me the question of why did they change the notation, just because its  easier to see that space-time is hyperbolic or are there other reasons?

Comment: Here is my paraphrase of Misner Thorne Wheeler’s “Farewell to ict”: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/327516/148184

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minkowski's complex Euclidean space vs. the real pseudo-Euclidean version](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/327318/)

Comment: Going back a 100 years or more this is how it was done.  It does not easily generalize to curved space models impo.

Comment: @KyleKanos yeah, mostly. Thanks