# Question about theory of relativity

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, velocity, observers

If you were running at a constant speed towards a light that is coming towards you and an other light was following you, from your perspective  how is it possible that both lights go at the same speed. I would think the light moving towards me would go faster than the light coming from behind which I am moving away from.

Comment: *I would think…* The universe doesn’t work according to your intuition. Your intuition works fine for speeds like 100 kph but not for really high speeds. Do you want the relativistic formula for combining speeds?

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't the classical addition of velocities apply to light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/695459/)

Comment: You might as well take your speed to be zero.

Comment: Related: [If I run along the aisle of a bus traveling at (almost) the speed of light, can I travel faster than the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7446/195139)

Comment: Related - [How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540485/37364)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79331/2451 and links therein.