# Minkowski product as Euclidean product plus spatial inversions

Tags: special-relativity

In special relativity, we write contravariant and covariant vectors respectively as $$A^\mu=(A^0, A^1, A^2, A^3), \quad A_\mu=(A_0, A_1, A_2, A_3).$$ Since $A_\mu=\eta_{\mu\nu}A^\nu$, we read off the relationship between each component, choosing the signature $(+,-,-,-$$)$: $$A_0=A^0, \quad A_1=-A^1, \quad A_2=-A^2, \quad A_3=-A^3 $$ and thus $A_\mu=(A^0, -A^1, -A^2, -A^3)$ in terms of the contravariant components. But in order to have $A^\mu A_\mu=(A^0)^2-(\mathbf A)^2$ as we should, with this notation where the metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ has been 'absorbed' into one of the vectors, we need to use the standard Euclidean product:
$$A^\mu\eta_{\mu\nu}A^\nu=A^\mu A_\mu= (A_0, A_1, A_2, A_3)^T(A^0, -A^1, -A^2, -A^3)=(A^0)^2-(\mathbf A)^2.$$ Does this mean that going into Minkowski space correspond to staying in the Euclidean space, but inverting the spatial coordinates of one of the vectors?

Comment: You can write the metric as a matrix, in which case the inner product becomes $\tilde A\eta \vec A$

Comment: This way of thinking has similarities with the “ict” trick to avoid the Minkowski (and Lorentz-signature) metrics. It might work in some special cases, but I think you’ll miss a lot of the physics. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/327516/148184

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we need to use the standard Euclidean product

I wouldn't call it a Euclidean product but rather the usual Einstein convention for summation over the repeated indices:

$$A_\mu A^\mu  = \sum_{\mu=0}^3A_\mu A^\mu = A_0 A^0 + A_1 A^1 + A_2 A^2 + A_3 A^3$$

This expression is the same in both Euclidean and Minkowski space. The distinction between them comes when you want to relate $A_\mu$ to $A^\mu$. As you correctly pointed out, in Minkowski this is done with the help of Minkowski metric and as a result you get

$$A_\mu A^\mu = (A^0)^2 - (\mathbf{A})^2$$

How you choose to interpret it is up to you: saying that

> going into Minkowski space correspond to staying in the Euclidean space, but inverting the spatial coordinates of one of the vectors

is equivalent to just using the Minkowski metric. I am not sure that this interpretation is going to help you gain physical intuition, though. It's better to just get accustomed to using Minkowski metric.

Comment: I think a potential source of confusion is the fact that $A^\mu$ can be used to mean both the four-vector and a specific component. In my post, I wrote $A_\mu A^\mu$ as the dot product of a row vector and a column vector. Once you write the *vector* $A_\mu$ in terms of the *components* $A^\mu$, then the summation convention and the standard Euclidean product are basically indistinguishable, right? Then I agree with you that it makes more sense to just use the standard conventions in any practical situation.

Comment: Dot product of a row and column vectors is yet another way of representing the summation convention. Euclidean product is superficially given by the same formula because Euclidean metric is just a unit matrix. There might be indeed a confusion between vectors and components. Either you use index-free notation and write inner product as $A^T\eta A$ (like Charlie pointed out in the comment to your post) with $A$ denoting the vector itself; or you use $A^\mu$ and $A_\mu$ denoting components of a contravariant and covariant vectors respectively and inner product is $A^\mu A_\mu$ with summation.