# Imaginary velocity components in geodesic

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, complex-numbers, wick-rotation

When we try to find the geodesic of a partical at rest, in the second term of the geodesic equation we use dt/dtau = 1. Shouldn’t it be i (for imaginary number), since the time component of the 4-velocity vector is imaginary?

Comment: Imaginary time isn't really taught in modern GR. See, for instance, [this Physics.SE Q&A](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/327318/25301) or [this Physics.SE Q&A](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121380/25301)

Comment: So, when we use imaginary time, vt.vt would result in a negative term. But if we use real time, vt.vt would result in a positive term. Won't that result in a wrong direction of acceleration?

Comment: The signs are handled by the [metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor).

Comment: So proper signs are handled by the Crystoffel symbols (which are derived from the metric tensor), so we don't need to worry about them in velocity components?

Comment: Yes, that is the case, AFAIK.

Comment: dt/dτ for a particle at rest is not 1 in general relativity, it is √gᵗᵗ which depends on position, spin, charge, mass (and if not at rest dt/dτ depends also on the gammafactor). √gᵗᵗ is 1 in special relativity, but you tagged [general relativity](http://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=1050#p1050)